# HTTP GET multi threading script

Tags: multithreading, http

Hi Stackoverflow community,

I would like to create a script that uses multi threading to create a high number of HTTP GET requests on a specific URL.

Which code language could be the most simple and fastest to obtain that?

Actually I tried to write something in Python but I would like to know your opinion about how to optimize it :) (the script should not wait for the server response but need only to generate a large amount of HTTP GET requests)

```
import requests
import threading


exitFlag = 0

url = "hxxps://xxx.com"


class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID

    def run(self):
        print ("T{} - {}".format(self.threadID, requests.get(url, verify=False).status_code))


# Create new threads
for i in range(500):
    thread = myThread(i).start()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're set on Python, have you considered [locust](http://locust.io)?

There are many HTTP load testing frameworks out there, though most probably are over complicated for what you are attempting to do, but that will leave room for future growth of your app.

BTW, if this is not your server, this will likely be viewed as a DoS attack depending on how many threads and how often. It could be considered criminal activity.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. No, the server is managed by me I am only doing some HTTP load test.